# New to javascript, Is there a way to create an idle game?

Tags: javascript

I'm running into this problem, I want to make a small idle game but I can't find it possible to have something loop forever and still run other code. here is what I have so far

```
var blops = 0;
var clickpower = 1;
var bps = 0;
var blopx = 240;
var blopy =220;

//Clicking the blob
onEvent("blob", "click", function() {
blops += clickpower;
blopx += 10;
blopy += 10;
setSize("blob", blopx, blopy);
sleep(90);
blopx += -10;
blopy += -10;
setSize("blob", blopx, blopy);
setText("blopsCount",blops);
});
//Debug BPS Toss Later
onEvent("bpsDebug", "click", function() {
bps += 1;
});
//Add BPS Tto Blops
while(true){
addBlops();
}

///FUNCTIONS
function addBlops(){
  sleep(1000);
  blops += bps;
}
//A Waiting Function
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is with "sleep" function this past week. So many questions with them.... All that function does is lock up the browser. It is not sleeping.... Use a timeout/interval

Comment: Don't use a loop.  It won't release control back to the UI thread.  Use `setInterval` or possibly `requestAnimationFrame`

Comment: @epascarello I am sorry, I am new to JS so I just looked up a wait timer thing, Ill try using timeouts, anyways, can ya answer my question (if it's not too much) (the issue is the while true loop because its not running any other code)

Comment: @Amy, I will try that

Comment: So the interval/timeout thing works instead of the sleep function, but I'm still looking for the answer on how to properly add the blops per second
@Amy

Comment: @ArisTheMage If I knew the answer, I would write an answer.  There's no need to prompt for one.

Comment: @ArisTheMage Thanks for letting me know?

Comment: youre going to need to be very specific and stop asking your homework questions here; your reputation will sink if you do. ask specific questions. dont paste your entire code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is locking up because you never release control. JavaScript is a single-threaded language. If you want to allow something else to happen, you need to release control by allowing your function to return. If you want to do something repeatedly, you can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to run code every certain number of milliseconds, or [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) which adds your function call to the event loop and allows other things like the UI to continue to work even though your function gets called repeatedly to update whatever it is you need it to do. There is some [good documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Choosing_the_right_approach) available to you if you want to weigh your options.